# InputSource with StringBuilder?

Tags: java, android, sax

Is there a way to create a sax.inputsource for a SAX parser, with a StringBuilder instead of a String? My program is crashing with out-of-memory when a large string is copied with the toString method.

I'm using tostring like:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(mystringbuilder.toString()))
```

I'm looking for a way to not copy an enourmous string, resulting in out-of-memory error.

Comment: Could you post the error and your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use your own implementation of *InputStream* that will use *StringBuilder* as a source of data. As an example you can check *ByteArrayInputStream* or *StringBufferInputStream*. And pass this *InputStream* into SAX parser.